# App Settings lost after upgrade to xubuntu 20.10

Tags: updates, xubuntu, settings

I just updated my i5 machine to Xubuntu 20.10 (with German language settings), and now in the menu the entry for app settings/update settings is no more available.
I already rebooted and searched via sudo apt update/ upgrade for newer files, but it does not appear.

Comment: What update method did you use, and what exact version did you have before? Was it Ubuntu, to which you later added the Xubuntu desktop, or was it a straight Xubuntu installation?

Comment: I looked around a little, and I don't think Xubuntu 20.10 was released yet, although vanilla Ubuntu 20.10 was just released. It is possible that your Xubuntu desktop environment remained as it was before, and you are now trying to run it on a 20.10 base, and there compatibility issues. So if you switch to the default Gnome desktop environment, there is a much better chance that things wiil work as intended.

Comment: Xubuntu 20.10 was released now.

Comment: It was 20.04 xubuntu LTS which I update via "sudo do-release-upgrade -d" from console. This worked also on another machine.